# How to set Password for sqlplus /as sysdba

Tags: oracle11g

I am new to Oracle. I would like to know how to set login password for sqlplus / as sysdba in oracle 11g.

I want to set the password for my next login, i dont want to login as **sqlplus / as sysdba**  since anyone can log in using sqlplus / as sysdba  and can easily access the data or change password for the existing user.I need to restrict the login.

Answer (score 15):

To set a new password you should (after connecting to the DB):

```
alter user SYS identified by "newpassword";
```

But if you want to prevent connecting without a password - `sqlplus / as sysdba`, then you need to add this:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES=none
```

in [sqlnet.ora](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/sqlnet.htm#BIIDAFFD)

Comment: **But if you want to prevent connecting without a password - sqlplus / as sysdba, then you need to add this:

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES=none in sqlnet.ora**                                                                                                                                   The same thing can be manually edited by some one and they can again change back to **SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES=NTS** so that they can login again -sqlplus / as sysdba

Comment: @user2064110, True, but the user that has write privileges to this file shouldn't be just "anyuser" (the same as connecting as sysdba can't be done by "anyuser"). If someone can get the admins password it's the same like getting SYS's password to the DB

Comment: Why i am asking is since say in a company 5 peoples are working and they are accessing the server with Admin userid and password and if some one changes some modifications in the server using sqlplus / as sysdba it will affect the rest of the peoples right so in-order to avoid we need to restrict the login by setting password.

Comment: @user2064110, this question may be more suitable to http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

Not just anyone can login using `sqlplus / as sysdba`. The OS user must be a member of the OS `DBA` group created to manage the database (this group can have a different name).

You should only be assigning real DBAs membership of this group. And, in my opinion, no one should ever login as `oracle` (assuming a Unix(-like) system here).

Comment: can you please give me an example of what this means "The OS user must be a member of the OS DBA group created to manage the database (this group can have a different name)."

Answer (score -1):

```
SQLPLUS username/password@identifier_name
```